# How to publish from multiple sources into one map - PUBNUB

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, pubnub

I want to implement pubnub connected car solution . But I can't find a way to publish from multiple sources into one map.

For example when I publish message like this:

```
message: [{"latlng":[37*Math.random(),-82*Math.random()]},
                 {"latlng":[37*Math.random(),-82*Math.random()]},
                 {"latlng":[37*Math.random(),-82*Math.random()]},
                 {"latlng":[37*Math.random(),-82*Math.random()]}]
      });
```

it takes it as 4 different taxi markers moving around but in real time every different taxi will publish fro different sources/pages. In that case if I send these 4 "latlng" from 4 different pages it takes it as one taxi.

Can you please tell me  how to implement such scenario?

Comment: wow, You just neglected my suggested edit and edited the post by yourself.It's ok for now. Because you still new here.Don't do it again.Because I spent more than 20 valuble minutes to edit your post

Comment: sorry for that but i am new here and i could not figure out how to accept your edit . pLease send it again and suggest me in comment how to accept it . I will do that.....regarding the code part shown earlier just skip it please as i figured out the error in that section

Comment: it's oki and  I understand your scenario, bcz I were like you once ago, if you figured out your answer for the question post it as "Answer your own  Question" ,refer this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PubNub EON Maps - Multiple Publish Sources

Have you looked into the [PubNub EON Framework](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/)?

There is an example on how to [publish from multiple sources and display as separate markers on the map](https://github.com/pubnub/eon-map).

Comment: Flight example on the link provided by you worked for me https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/map/flight/ Thanks.